# Who invented a way to measure the consistency of logical statements using cosine distance?

Tags: logic, metric-spaces

It seems as if the consistency of logical propositions is amenable to being measured using cosine distance. let $\ell$ be such a metric.

1. For any proposition $P$, it is the case that $P$ is consistent with itself, so $\ell(P, P) = 1$
2. For any proposition $P$, it is the case that $P$ is not consistent with its negation, so $\ell(P, \neg P) = -1$.
3. However, it is additionally the case that a proposition $P$ and its negation $\neg P$ can be consistent with another set of logical statements. Let $P$ be the parallel postulate of euclidean geometry, and let $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ be the remaining four axioms. Then it is the case that $\ell(P, A_i) = 0$. That is, one statement can be independent from another.

Surely some smarter mathematician saw this and created a way to measure the cosine distance of logical propositions. Who is that mathematician, and where can I find their papers?

Comment: But the parallel postulate **is** consistent with the remaining four axioms. Perhaps you intend $\ell(P,Q) = 1$ to hold precisely if $\Gamma \vdash P \leftrightarrow Q$ for some fixed $\Gamma$?

Comment: @Z.A.K. Thank you for pointing out spotty thinking. I am going to update the OP to better clarify what I meant. I don't know enough about sequent calculus to determine if what you wrote matches my intention, but it might.